# KendoUI Slider: can I generate a SLIDE or CHANGE event without mouse interaction?

Tags: jquery, events, slider, mouseevent, kendo-ui

I am working on an [hexagonal pattern generator](http://bit.ly/hexagrid) that uses KendoUI widgets as GUI.

I am trying to implement a `Randomize()` function that would animate the slider handles to a random position. The function is called when clicking the Randomize! button.
This should generate a `slide` or `change` event on the Kendo slider which in turn would fire the `changeYcomp(e)` callback that calls the `init()` function updating the pattern.

**Markup for the slider**:

```
 <div class="sliderwrapper" id="yslider">
                            <label for="ycompSlider">Y variation</label>
          <input id="ycompSlider" class="slider" />
 </div>
```

**Script for the callback**:

```
function changeYcomp(e) {
    kendoConsole.log("New slide value is: " + e.value);
    ycomp = e.value;
    init();
}
```

**Parameters assignment for the slider**:

```
$("#ycompSlider").kendoSlider({
                                slide: changeYcomp,
                                change: changeYcomp,
                                min: -10,
                                max: 10,
                                smallStep: 1,
                                largeStep: 10,
                                value: 0
                            });
```

**Randomize function**:

```
function Randomize() {
    console.log("Randomizing!")
    $("#yslider .k-draghandle").animate({
      left: Math.round(Math.random()*130-7)
    });

}
```

Unfortunately neither changing the `.k-draghandle` position via CSS animation, nor changing any of the slider's HTML attributes fires any event.

**I am assuming that the slider is listening for mouse events only.**

For now the only alternative would be to manage the slider handle position and the updating function separately by adding `step` functionality on the animation.

I would like to avoid this as it would either force some redesign or involve duplication.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `trigger()` function on a widget to fire its events:

```
$("#yslider").data("kendoSlider").trigger("slide", { value: 123 });
```

The caveat is that you have to specify the event object that it passes to the callbacks. Fortunately the event for slide only contains the `value` property.

So you can do:

```
var slider = $("#slider").data("kendoSlider");
slider.value(5);
slider.trigger("slide", { value: slider.value() });
```

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rally25rs/66Wsj/1/) for a working example.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't find that method in the slider documentation and I didn't think of looking up prototype methods.

Comment: Now the only remaining issue is that I'm using the step callback of JQuery.animate() to fire the trigger method for each step of the value change and doing so on 4 sliders seems to hog down the CPU as the init() method has to redraw the canvas multiple times per step.

Comment: Yeah I could see that causing some slowness. Would it be possible to just do the `.trigger()` once at the end of the `.animate()`?

Comment: Yes, that would be indeed possible, but you would only see the slider moving without the visual feedback of the pattern changing. I'll try to figure out a way to call the init() method only once per step even though I have 4 concurring animate() functions working.